# Segmentation fault: 11 after Xcode upgrade

Tags: swift, xcode, segmentation-fault

please help on this error message:

2. While silgen emitFunction SIL function "@$S6QRCart6CartVCC9tableView_12cellForRowAtSo07UITableE4CellCSo0jE0C_10Foundation9IndexPathVtF".
   for 'tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)' at /Users/Stenly/Downloads/QRCartGeo/QRCart/CartVC.swift:89:5
   error: Segmentation fault: 11

This is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indePath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Parents
    let cellIdentifierParents = "cell"

    let CartCell: CartCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifierParents) as? CartCell
    let cellObject = loadedCart[indePath.row]
    CartCell?.selectionStyle = .none
    CartCell?.lblItem.text = (cellObject as AnyObject).object(forKey: "item") as? String
    CartCell?.lblSize.text = (cellObject as AnyObject).object(forKey: "size") as? String
    CartCell?.lblPrice.text = ((cellObject as AnyObject).object(forKey: "price") as? String!)! + " €"
    CartCell?.lblPrice.text = CartCell?.lblPrice.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: ",")

    var total = Float()
    for item in loadedCart {
        let price : NSString = ((item as AnyObject).object(forKey: "price") as? NSString)!

        let priceTruncate = price.replacingOccurrences(of: "€", with: "")

        let a:Float? = Float(priceTruncate)
        total = total + a!

        self.lblTotalOfCart.text = String(format : "SE: %.2f €",total)
        self.lblTotalOfCart.text = self.lblTotalOfCart.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: ",")
    }
    let deleteItem = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.deleteItem(_:)))

    CartCell?.btnRemoveOutlet.addGestureRecognizer(deleteItem)

    CartCell?.btnRemoveOutlet.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
    return CartCell!

}
```

Comment: I too am getting the same error.

Comment: Try to rename your function. Generate it again over fix proposal. Copy the contant into the new generated function and delete the renamed function.